# python kivy isuues with pos_hint for image

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get a image to position itself at the bottom right hand corner of the screen with pos_hint but it always leaves a gap between the bottom of the image and the screen, im still very new to kivy and have looked around for a solution but cant find anything that helps, thanks in advance

```py
class Building(Image):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.source = 'Building.png'
    self.size_hint = 0.4,1
    self.pos_hint = {'x':0.7, 'y':0.1}
```

This is where i call it

```py
self.build = Building()
self.add_widget(self.build)
```

[This is a link to the how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egNt9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues that may be causing the gap. One is that your code:

```
self.pos_hint = {'x':0.7, 'y':0.1}
```

is setting a gap of one tenth of the container height.

The second issue is that `Image`, by default, will not stretch the underlying image, and will not distort the image (stretching more in one direction than the other). So, you can get what you want by modifying your `Building` class like this:

```
class Building(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'Building.png'
        self.size_hint = 0.4,1
        self.pos_hint = {'right':1.0, 'y':0}   # position image at right, bottom
        self.allow_stretch = True  # allow image to be stretched
        self.keep_ratio = False  # allow distortion
```